# aws - should I create two lambda function to handle dynamodb query and non-query use case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have an "Banner" Table.
There are 2 possible use cases for this table.

**1.get all banner data from table**

My lambda function might like below:

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const params = {
        TableName : "Banner",
    };

    try{
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
        statusCode = 200
    }catch(err){
        responseBody = `Unabel to get products: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: responseBody
    }

    return response
}
```

**2.Query by user partition key/GSI**

I may need to query based on banner id or banner title to get the corresponding table.

At first, I was thinking combine this two user case in one single lambda function.
until I opened below post.

[aws - how to set lambda function to make dynamic query to dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912065/aws-how-to-set-lambda-function-to-make-dynamic-query-to-dynamodb)

One of the comments provide a way for me to do the dynamic query for these 2 user case, but he/she also mention that:

```
you are giving anyone invoke the request the ability to put any query in the request, that might put you vulnerable to some type of SQL Injection attacks.
```

This makes me thinking whether I should separate these 2 user cases in two lambda function?
What is the general practise for these kinds of things?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, also if the "SQL Injection" can be blocked it's good to separate this into 2 functions, Lambda handler should be single responsibility. If you want to reuse the code you can create some common DAL that you can create with the common code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes down to personal preference, but I'd recommend splitting the functionality into two lambdas.

It sounds like you have two access patterns:

1. Get all banners
2. Get banners by user

I would probably implement these with two separate lambdas.  If I were exposing this functionality via an API, I'd probably create two endpoints:

1. GET /banners. (fetches all banners)
2. GET /users/[user_id]/banners. (fetches all banners for a given user)

Each of these endpoints would route to their own lambda that services the specific request.  If you serve the request with a single lambda, you'll have to introduce logic within your lambdas to determine which type of request you're fulfilling.  I can't imagine what you'd gain by using only one lambda.

Keep your lambda code focused on a single responsibility, it'll make it easier to develop, test, and debug.